# Control size of a label Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to control the size of a label inside a Ruby on Rails project. 
The code looks like this:

```
        <p>
        <%= f.label :email %>
         <p>
        </p>
        <%= f.text_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
        </p>
```

I want to be able to control the label width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using bootstrap, This thing will help you.

```
 <%= f.label :email, class: "control-label" %>
```

You can also create your custom class, add to the label tag as well incase nothing works.